# Striking off a digit from each of the numbers written in seven rows, while preserving arithmetical operations

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

#### Problem

Strike off any digit from each number in seven rows (need not be at same place) and combine the same operations with 3 digit numbers to get the same addition. After this strike off another digit from all and add all the numbers to get the same 2 digit number perform the same. Process again with 1 digit Numbers. Give the numbers in 7 rows at each stage.

I got this from a Q bank, there was no answer.

```
   1 2 3 4

+ 3 4 5 5

----------

4 6 8 9

- 2 3 4 5

----------

2 3 4 4

+ 1 2 5 4

------------

3 6 9 8
```

**My Solution got stuck**

**Solution 1**

I just gone this much but got stuck here ....

```
1 2 3 +
3 4 5 
--------
4 6 8 -
2 3 4
-------
2 3 4 +
xxxxxxxx Stopped
```

**Solution 2**

```
1 2 4 +
3 4 5 
--------
4 6 9 -
2 3 5
-------
2 3 4 +
xxxxxxxx Stopped
```

Answer (score 1):

```
1 3 4 +
3 5 5 
--------
4 8 9 -
2 4 5
-------
2 4 4 +
1 2 5
-------
3 6 9
```

Comment: thanks . but 1 2 3 4 + 3 4 5 5 <--- Removed  2 and  4 (same place)

Comment: @Nifty, the question says, *"need not be at same place"* which suggests they can be in the same place if you choose (or not, if you choose)